# error with ractive sortable

Tags: javascript, decorator, jquery-ui-sortable, ractivejs

I created a demo to test the  Ractive decorator: "ractive-decorators-sortable.js" and what I tought would  be a simple test does not look  like it will ever sort anything. It also give me the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: sourceKeypath.lastIndexOf is not a function". Here is my code:

```
<body>
  <h1>Ractive sort</h1>
  <div id='container'></div>

  <script id='template' type='text/ractive'>
  <ul class="reorderable browsers">
      {{#list}}
        <li decorator='sortable'>{{.}}</li>
      {{/list}}
  </ul>
  </script>

  <script>
    var ractive = new Ractive({
    el: '#container',
    template: '#template',
    data:  { list: [ 'Firefox', 'Chrome', 'Internet Explorer', 'Opera',               'Safari', 'Maxthon' ] }
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fixed in the newest version of the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: meanwhile, it's probably fixed

---

The current version of the plugin is apparently a bit old and not up to date compared to ractive.

In the meantime, you can use this one, provided by the community:

https://github.com/Skyrpex/ractive-decorators-sortable

Which appears to work for Ractive 0.7 (but not yet 0.8):

http://jsfiddle.net/wn9fnev9/

```
Somehow, putting a jsfiddle requires adding code ...silly
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in the plugin. It has been raised on May 2014 and still not solved. If any other version of ractivejs than the one supplied with the plugin is used (Ractive - v0.3.9 - 2013-12-26), it won't drag and will give an error.
See: https://github.com/ractivejs/Ractive-decorators-sortable/issues/3.
Too bad, I guess I'll have to use either HTML5 or JQueryUI.